# Is there a substitution for C#'s await in C++/CX? Win10

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, c++-cx

UWP, Win10, C++/CX

I want to use WinRT async functions synchronously in C++/CX, like C#'s await does. Is there a substitution for C#'s await in C++/CX?

I have read this article [__await](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/20/asynchronous-programming-in-c-using-resumable-functions-and-await.aspx), but it doesn't work, perhaps it's for win8 and not supported in win10, or I'm wrong.

BTW, Concurency::create_task(option).get() meets my need, but too long, and it can't work on UI thread ( I don't know why, can you tell me if you know? )

Thank you :)

Comment: I don't know an answer to your question, but I'd suggest you just import C# DLLs into your project. Here is an example.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/695387/Calling-Csharp-NET-methods-from-unmanaged-C-Cplusp
So you will be able to access the cool c#/ .net methods from your C++ project

Comment: Adding resumable functions to C++ is an [ISO proposal](http://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/resumable-functions-async-and-await.html).  They generally move at a snail's pace, you'll at least have to wait until C++17.  If you want to use the [experimental headers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/12/resumable-functions-in-c.aspx) then you can do so today with VS2015.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I cannot think of a compelling reason to block the UI thread. If you need to serialize operations, use a [continuation task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750044.aspx). @ProblemSlover: If all you have is a hammer, every problem starts to look like a nail. And now you have two problems.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for your answer. In fact, our goal is to deliver a existing project to WinRT, the project has too much legacy code.

Comment: For example, if there is API using win32 api to save file, while other code is paltform-independent, so it will be lowest-cost to reimp the API via WinRT and keep other code unchanged. Unfortunately WinRT async apis can't satisfy us, that's why I ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: As of VS 2015 Update 2, VC++ supports `co_await` for production use (although it is under a special flag because it hasn't been standardized yet). You can see more in [this MSDN video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P489).

Note that `await` in C# is **not** a synchronous call; there is no blocking involved. It simply gives the illusion of sequential execution.

C++ explicitly blocks calling `get` on the UI thread to avoid hanging the UI.

Comment: Thank you. I am not familiar with c#. It sound amazing then I have a test.

Comment: As you said, it won't be blocked if await in UI thread. Can you tell me what is UI thread doing during await? I suspect it go back event loop and proceed handling events. Will it be a problem to keep logic sequence? For example, if a event handler depends on the previous one's result, will it make code confusing? thanks :)

Comment: You're correct; it keeps running the event loop so you need to protect your code from re-entrance (eg) by disabling your UI controls until the async method has completed.

Comment: Do you mean that C++'s get is different from C#'s await? C++'s get can't go back event loop. Is this the reason why we can't wait on UI thread with C++?

Comment: Eventually I get C++'s __await work :). It do hang UI, not same as C#'s await. Thank you!

Comment: get hang UI, not __await

Comment: `task.get()` for C++ is the equivalent of `Task.Result` in .NET -- it will try to block until the results are available. .NET allows this on the UI thread - even though it can potentially deadlock - whereas C++ explicitly disallows it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the way to use await, however it's limited.

use await in VS2015
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/12/resumable-functions-in-c.aspx

await and yield are experimental. If you want to use them, remember they are only supported on x64, and set some compiler options:

- add /await
- disable /RTC
- /ZI -> /Zi

Comment: ref:https://paoloseverini.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/async-await-in-c/ (this article is a bit out-of-date, but still useful)
https://paoloseverini.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/stackless-coroutines-with-vs2015/

Comment: `co_await` is now supported on all architectures for production use!